# extract full month name from date in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

What a quick way to extract the full month name from a date in redshift.

`2022-01-01 ->> January`

Answer (score 3):

The to_char() function does this:

to_char(, 'Month')

For example

```
select to_char('2022-01-01'::date, 'Month');
```

produces 'January'.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula for creating calculated field for the month name.

```
 [ifelse(
   month=1, "January",
   month=2, "February",
   month=3, "March",
   month=4, "April",
   month=5, "May",
   month=6, "June", 
   month=7, "July",
   month=8, "August",
   month=9, "September", 
   month=10, "October", 
   month=11, "November",
   month=12, "December", null
   ) ]
```